# A/B Testing Options for UI / UX Metrics vs Goals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface, user-experience

I'm needing an A/B testing solution that is not "conversion" or goal oriented.  What options exist for Rails?  It needs to be a mechanism that interleaves routes to various pages defined for a "group" (such as I want to interleave between these 3 views for this particular page round robin).

My primary goal is to interleave pages (routes) as users visit them.  So, for example, when a user hits "/" it would load up the default page one time and then another route such as "/front-page-2" on the next load of "/".  Or any other page for that matter.  I need to thoroughly test between a number of variations and allow the system to switch these around so that all pages being tested get a round robin opportunity.

The main goal here is to get some UI / UX testing in place with MouseFlow.com.  I am able to record user heatmaps, click counts, hover results, etc. however I must be able to give all of the pages a fair chance in order to make judgement calls based on the metrics I get back from MouseFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with VisualWebOptimizer.com if anyone's interested.  I found it is working exactly as I needed it and allows me to work with MouseFlow.com as well to accomplish our goals.